# How to call services when moving one ViewModel to another

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, viewmodel

I have `LandingPageViewModel` with GetHomework `Button`. If I click on GetHomework `Button` it takes to `HomeworkPageViewModel`.

Now the problem is, where to call my service to get Homework data?

In `LandingPageViewModel`s `GetHomeworkExecute()` method and hold all Homework record in public accessible variable OR use `NavigationParameter` to pass to the next page then use it in `HomeworkPageViewModel`(or in other `ViewModel`s if holding record in global variable).

OR

In `HomeworkPageViewModel`s `OnNavigatingTo()`(act as onload I think) method overridden by `INavigatedAware`

What is the good way to call the service when moving one `ViewModel` to another?

Comment: If there are multiple views that navigate to the homework view, would you like to make all of them get the homework data just to pass it to the homework view? (not that you **will** have multiple views). Not really. On the other hand, if a view needs the data and gets it by itself (`OnNavigatingTo`), it becomes idependent of any other view that calls it.

Comment: I do not have multiple views to navigate to Hw, I have only one Homework menu in my application. So where should write my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it into `HomeworkPageViewModel`, probably in the constructor (unless it's an `async` call). Rationale: if the `HomeworkPageViewModel` can do it (because it does not need additional info), then let it do it. Try not to spread out things, keep your code together.